# Union n amount of tables in mariadb and find the distinct value based on timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, distinct

I need to make a search on multiple database tables. Since all tables have the same structure(same columns, they are actually archived data for the same table) I can use UNION ALL to combine them all.

However, the challenge is I need to get the distinct value for Username Column and for every Username value I need to find the earliest Time_stamp after using UNION ALL for all archived data.

I went through the documentation and googled for a quite some time and couldn't find a satisfying solution withing MySQL.

The only way I can think of is to write some external code to search the values with UNION ALL for each Username. And run the query 1 by 1. Knowing that I have 100k distinct Username listed in the database, it will take quite some time. I have already started this script, however, it feels really inefficient and waste of resources.

```sql
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE `USERNAME` LIKE 'USERNAMEXXX'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE `USERNAME` LIKE 'USERNAMEXXX'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table3 WHERE `USERNAME` LIKE 'USERNAMEXXX'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE `USERNAME` LIKE 'USERNAMEXXX'
ORDER BY TIME_STAMP ASC
LIMIT 1
```

Above SQL query gives me what I want for every username but I need to iterate it for each distinct Username.

Just to add, I have another table that holds all the distinct Username values. I use that table to populate the search on my external code solution.

Is there any way to achieve this using native SQL, without external scripting? Something that combines distinct, union all and order by timestamp asc limit 1.

Comment: Have you considered partitioning?

Comment: @Strawberry Sorry, thats something I am not aware of. Could you please guide me more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, you can use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timestamp) as seqnum
      FROM ((SELECT t.* FROM table1 t) UNION ALL
            (SELECT t.* FROM table2 t) UNION ALL
            (SELECT t.* FROM table3 t) UNION ALL
            (SELECT t.* FROM table4 t)
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

In earlier versions, you can use variables:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (@rn := IF(@u = username, @rn + 1,
                        IF(@u := username, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY username ORDER BY timestamp) as seqnum
      FROM ((SELECT t.* FROM table1 t) UNION ALL
            (SELECT t.* FROM table2 t) UNION ALL
            (SELECT t.* FROM table3 t) UNION ALL
            (SELECT t.* FROM table4 t)
            ORDER BY username, timestamp
           ) t CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @u := '', @rn := 0) params
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

The above assume that you want all the columns.  If you just want the minimum timestamp and username, use aggregation:

```
SELECT username, MIN(timestamp),
FROM ((SELECT t.* FROM table1 t) UNION ALL
      (SELECT t.* FROM table2 t) UNION ALL
      (SELECT t.* FROM table3 t) UNION ALL
      (SELECT t.* FROM table4 t)
     ) t
GROUP BY username;
```

Comment: I couldnt get these to work. What are the t.* for? Do I need to change it to my table? If yes, with what?

Comment: Earlier versions?

Comment: tried them all, unfortunately all threw an error. I might be doing something wrong. What is the t.* for?

Comment: `t` is the alias assigned for all the tables. `t.*` is just similar to your `SELECT * FROM table1`. Since Gordon assigned the table alias as `t` like in `SELECT t.* FROM table1 t`, he took the `t.*` to specify column from which table alias he wanted to return. Similarly it can be written (without alias) `SELECT table1.* FROM table1`. This is particularly useful for queries with joins and to shorten table names because sometimes there are table names like this `t_purchaseorderdetailusedby` which is too long especially if you have `JOIN` query.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand right your question

You could use   min for earliest timestam   min(my_time_stamp) and UNION (for return distinct )

```
select  username, min(my_time_stamp)
from  table1 
group  by username 
union  
select  username, min(my_time_stamp)
from  table2 
group  by username 
union
select  username, min(my_time_stamp)
from  table3 
group  by username 
....

union
select  username, min(my_time_stamp)
from  tableN
group  by username 

order by username
```

Comment: This satisfies my need but CPU spikes with this command. Is that expected if the tables are big or is there a way to modify this command to make it smoother?

Comment: Your question  is "Is there any way to achieve this using native SQL, without external scripting" ?  .. and  my answer  clearly answer  at this question in positive way ..  for the CPU load  ..  The alternative is to consume at least one CPU this way or consume as much CPU iterantly for each username on the same data several times .. the first hypothesis is more efficient ..